# CannotUnloadAppDomain Mbunit and CCNET

Tags: exception, appdomain, mbunit, gallio, ccnet-config

Our CCNET build system has been running just fine since we set it up. Recently we moved to another room and changed one IP address on our system and we are getting CannotUnloadAppDomainException from MbUnit which is run from NCover. I have checked our SVN logs to make sure there were no changes and there aren't. Has anyone experienced this before or have any ideas what I should be looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Gallio](http://gallio.org) runs your tests in [**IsolatedAppDomain** mode by default](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools%3agallio_test_runners). The error indicates that the AppDomain sandbox cannot be unloaded probably due to a critical error involving resource lock, multi-thread race condition, or something like an out of memory issue or a stack overflow.

You certainly need more information to diagnose the root cause of the problem. What you can do:

- Run manually your tests with [Gallio.Echo](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=tools%3aecho) and have a look at the test report or at the console output.
- You may also want to run your tests in **IsolatedProcess** or **Local** modes instead. This will make the whole process to collapse faster; it may highlight the underlying issue.
- You could also ask the question in the [Gallio User Group](http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-user).

Comment: We are still using the old MbUnit as we are actually in the process now of transitioning to NUnit for .NET 4.0. It was working fine until we changed the IP Address that was pointing to our iMac because we plugged it in somewhere else and the IP changed and it just began to fail at that point. I'll try and look into it some more today and run sections of tests to see which are giving me that issue.

Comment: Someone decided that hardcoding a value into our test suite was a good idea and our Socket connection was sending messages to some random IP.